# How to print one by one value in a list which is inside a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

So I have been trying to figure out how to print a value one by one that is in a list which is inside a dict. I will post a code below how it looks and also comments aswell.

```
class Notifications():
    def __init__(self):

        self.discordFiltered = {'swedish': ['https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/zeASB62I35Fpssm',
                                          'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/YdfzrT3-tp55MMfxq'],

                                'mixed': ['https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v-a62eZdnwGO95kmZ',
                                        'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v9_oyW_IzuncYo6LEGS']
        }

        self.discordUnfiltered = {'swedish': ['https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/WjFoBneVWMaI9',
                                            'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yqG_aMU8dM4PSb'],

                                  'mixed': ['https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/F1iQ2T4ZUa2rOi',
                                           'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/EGgb9XV95Nbu_bb']
        }


    def sendToDiscord(self, item, isTrueFalse, directory: Path = Path(r"./slack")):
        for filepath in directory.glob("*.json"): #Will loop only twice because there is only 2 json files. Thrill.json and HelloWorld.json
            with open(filepath.resolve()) as slackAttachment:
                data = json.loads(slackAttachment.read())

                data["attachments"][0]["footer"] = "{} | {}]".format(data["attachments"][0]["footer"], datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d [%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])

                print(item.get('webhook')) #Will print swedish or mixed
                print(isTrueFalse) #Will print either True or False

                #If item.get('webhook') is mixed and isTrueFalse is True -> print discordFiltered Mixed first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
                #If item.get('webhook') is mixed and isTrueFalse is False -> print discordUnfiltered Mixed first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
                #If item.get('webhook') is swedish and isTrueFalse is True -> print discordFiltered Swedish first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
                #If item.get('webhook') is swedish and isTrueFalse is False -> print discordUnfiltered Swedish first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
```

My issue here is that I currently don't know how I am able to do the if statements in a correct way and also how I am able to print out one by one value from a list that is inside a dict.

And I wonder how I am able to do those examples:

```
#If item.get('webhook') is mixed and isTrueFalse is True -> print discordFiltered Mixed first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
#If item.get('webhook') is mixed and isTrueFalse is False -> print discordUnfiltered Mixed first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
#If item.get('webhook') is swedish and isTrueFalse is True -> print discordFiltered Swedish first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
#If item.get('webhook') is swedish and isTrueFalse is False -> print discordUnfiltered Swedish first URL (Then second URL on next loop)
```

Comment: You say that **IsTrueFalse** will print as either 'True' or 'False'. This would be the case if this were a string or a bool. Which is it?

Comment: It is a bool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that I may have totally misunderstood your question. If so, please comment and I will re-attempt a solution or delete this one.

Outside the loop have a variable url_index initialized to 0. At the end of the loop increment this variable. The assumption is that we will not be looping more than twice, so this variable will take on the values 0 and then 1.

```
key = item.get('webhook') # 'swedish' or 'mixed'
if isTrueFalse:
    discordFilteredList = self.discordFiltered[key]
    print(discordFilteredList[url_index])
else:
    discordUnfilteredList = self.discordUnfiltered[key]
    print(discordUnfilteredList[url_index])
```

The above can be expressed more concisely, but I wanted it to be clear.

Comment: Hey man! Sorry for late response but this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! :)